# open every file in seperate folders using a batch file

Tags: batch-file, for-loop

okay, so I have written a little script of code :

```
    for /R %%f in (*.acd) do C:\Users\jelle\Downloads\quickbms\quickbms.exe D:\assetto_corsa_acd.bms %%f "\data"
```

but the problem is that the file data.acd will be extracted using quickbms.exe to a data folder in the main folder my batch file is located in stead of in the /data folder located in the folder where the data.acd file is, so x:\carname(folder_with_data.acd_in_it)\data
but i can't get that to work,

so my question is how do i get quickbms to extract the acd file to the folder where the acd file is located instead of where the batch file is located? 
**Also note that quickbms is in my path**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Fine. And what is your specific programming-related on-topic question? Please read the [tour] and learn [ask] here! Regard that StackOverflow is not a free code/script writing service!

Comment: edited with a question now and also a sample of my code. I understand that this isn't just a place to get free code writing, but i have been struggling with this for a couple of hours and i cant find out how to fix this.

Comment: Your posted script appears to be running two lines instead of only one!

Comment: It is one line, but that's not formatted right in the post, changed it to the correct format.

Comment: If QuickBMS is in your `%PATH%` there's no need to provide a full path to it, you can just use `quickbms` or `quickbms.exe`, whichever you prefer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your posted script appears to be running two lines instead of only one.

Based on the following usage:

```bat
quickbms.exe [options] <script.BMS> <input_archive/folder> [output_folder]
```

I would suggest something like this:

```bat
@Echo Off
Rem Full path to QuickBMS
Set "eBMS=%UserProfile%\Downloads\quickbms\quickbms.exe"
Rem Full path to BMS script
Set "sBMS=D:\assetto_corsa_acd.BMS"
Rem BMS Options
Set "oBMS=-o -d"
Rem The source directory path to recurse (. is current, %~1 is arg[0])
Set "sDIR=."
Rem The sourcefile extension
Set "sEXT=.acd"
Rem The output directory path (.\ relevant to current, %~2 is arg[1])
Set "tOUT=.\data"

For /R "%sDIR%" %%A In (*%sEXT%) Do "%eBMS%" %oBMS% "%sBMS%" "%%A" "%tOUT%"
```

*Fill in the `Set` command lines according to the `Rem`arks and give it a try reporting back any issues as necessary.*

Comment: okay, so i tried the script, but i kept getting this : The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.

Comment: so i just entered the code manually into cmd, and it asks me to overwrite  files, or create a new folder, i enter yes, but the files don't get moved or extracted at all

Comment: @JelleVolkerink, you should be using one of either the `-o`, `-k` or `-K` options these should either automatically overwrite without asking, keep existing files without overwriting, _(skip all)_, or automatically rename the files if duplicates already exist. There's a place in the script to insert whichever of those you require, e.g. `Set "oBMS=-o"`. _Please note my answer assumes that you know how to use the software you've chosen to script, this site is for script help not software help_.

Comment: Optionally, if QuickBMS is in your `%PATH%` there's no need to provide a full path to it, you can just use `Set "eBMS=quickbms.exe"` in the script above if you prefer!

Comment: the only problem is that the acd gets extracted to a seperate data folder instead of in the subfolder where the data.acd is located.

Comment: @JelleVolkerink, you need to better explain where you want the files to be extracted to! For possible future reference, you may also wish to investigate the `-d` and `-D` options too!

Comment: -d did the trick, now every file is extracted in the subfolder data where data.adc is located, thank you very much for your help!

Comment: @JelleVolkerink, please, provide me with any modifications you made to the currently posted answer in order that I can edit it to better reflect your intended goal. Then you could mark the answer as accepted as your ideal solution.

Comment: see the next answer for the finalized script.

Comment: @JelleVolkerink, please delete your answer, all I needed was what you changed, and it appears only to have been the two options you added to the `%oBMS%` variable. Incidentally, that uses an `-a` option which I'm guessing is a typo, because you're not passing arguments, I've updated my code to use the `-o` and `-d` options as previously advised.